# How to fake error 504 in node-express server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, express, request

I want to check a code that I wrote, which retry a request when error 504 occurs (only one more time). Can someone help me how to fake an error to check it?
(The server is Node express, the client AngularJs).

The old code was:

```
this.update = function(endpoint, body, config) {
        return $http.put(endpoint, body, config || {});
    };
```

My new code is:

```
this.update = function(endpoint, body, config) {
        var updateRequest = $http.put(endpoint, body, config || {}). catch(function (error) {
            if (error.status === 504){
                return $http.put(endpoint, body, config || {});
            }
        });

        return updateRequest;
    };
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

provide the `timeout` option in `$http.put` with 0 value.

```
this.update = function(endpoint, body, config) {
       var timeoutConfig = Object.assign({},config);
           timeoutConfig.timeout = 0; // provide the time in millisecond for waiting
        var updateRequest = $http.put(endpoint, body, timeoutConfig || {}). catch(function (error) {
            if (error.status === 504){
                return $http.put(endpoint, body, config || {});
            }
        });

        return updateRequest;
    };
```